# SwiftUI: @FetchResult in a computed variable

Tags: core-data, swiftui

For an iOS app written in SwiftUI I have lists of recipes each associated with a food category each accessible to user control. I need to make lists of the recipes by category and have tried the following code (along with many variations) (this originally had "ForEach" incorrectly in place of "for")

```
struct RecipeListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(
         entity: FoodCategory.entity(),
         sortDescriptors: [
             NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FoodCategory.name, ascending: true)
         ]
     )var foodCategories: FetchedResults<FoodCategory>
    var recipeListsForCategory:[[Recipe]] {
    var recipeLists:[[Recipe]] = []
    for aCategory in foodCategories {
        @FetchRequest(
            entity: Recipe.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [
                NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Recipe.name, ascending: true),
            ],
            predicate: (NSPredicate(format: "foodCategory == %@", aCategory))
            )var recipesInCategory: FetchedResults<Recipe>
            recipeLists.append (Array(recipesInCategory))
        }
        return recipeLists
    }
```

Now I get the error message Property wrappers are not yet supported on local properties" If I can't use @Fetch inside of a computed variable, how can I get lists of a managed variable filtered by another managed variable?

Comment: The `ForEach` is not loop control flow, it is SwiftUI View container. It is not appropriate tool for your case.

Comment: I think you are using CoreData. wrong. It would seem what you really want is a relationship between your recipes and their food categories. Then you only need to fetch your food categories and access the recipes that are associated with each category through that. I would check out this [Hacking With Swift tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/core-data-introduction). You are not going to be able to access ANY variable like you are trying, whether computed or not, as they haven't been initialized.